# protractor .text() or .html() is not defined?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm new to **protractor (With Coffeescript)** when I run the following test case, I get this error.

```
    it 'Check if the visitor count is incremented', ->
        expect(By.css('#total-visitor-value').text().length).toBeTruthy()
```

I get this error:

```
✗ Check if the visitor count is incremented (0.016 secs)
  - TypeError: Object By.cssSelector("#total-visitor-value") has no method 'text'
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the method to use is `getText()` not `text()`.

Try this:
`expect(by.css('#total-visitor-value').getText().length).toBeTruthy()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Buck Kimbriel, I still get the same error:       - TypeError: Object By.cssSelector("#total-visitor-value") has no method 'getText'

Comment: My guess would be that protractor isn't finding that element. Try logging the return of `by.css('#total-visitor-value')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to reference the element. Also, your CSS lookup is looking for an element by its ID value, so use by.id instead. The .getText() call returns a promise, you have to account for it resolving as well. Your test should read something like:

```
expect(element(by.id('total-visitor-value')).getText().length).toBeTruthy();
```

Here is the reference for Protractor Locators: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/locators

You can still reference it using by.css if you want (your reference is right) but by.id is more precise.

Comment: `expect()` in protractor is "patched" and resolves promises implicitly. There is no need for `then()` in this case..but, good catch about the missing `element()`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it still fails. This is what i get `      - TypeError: Object By.cssSelector("#total-visitor-value") has no method 'getText'`

Comment: Good to know about expect() being patched. I must be on an old version. Thanks @alecxe.

Comment: @TechnoCorner you are still missing the element() then. That is what has the getText() method.

Comment: I am not sure about "expect() in protractor is "patched" and resolves promises implicitly." Usually it does, but I've seen it to not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, the method you are looking for is [`getText()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText). Also, instead of checking `.length` of the text, I would use a `toBeNonEmptyString()` jasmine matcher from [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers):

```
expect(element(by.css('#total-visitor-value')).getText()).toBeNonEmptyString();
```

Note the readability.

Comment: - TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toBeNonEmptyString' . this is what i get

Comment: @TechnoCorner have added `require("jasmine-expect");` to `onPrepare()`?